# find page is favorited by user

Tags: jquery, asp.net

could i able to find out current page (visited by user in web application) is Favorited page in user's browser using asp.net or jQuery?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of doing this due to browser security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access this with javascript. It will be a serious security flaw if a web page could find user's bookmarks (and then store them in a database for example).

Comment: True - its just not possible, the browser is the users domain and hence can't (and shouldn't) be accessed by any websites

Comment: No it isn't possible with Asp.net or any other server technology. A browser plug-in could possibly to do it, still it isn't a good idea.

Comment: just like cookie, can't we access Favorited item?